# Lower bound for the chromatic number in terms of minimum feedback vertex set

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $MFVS(G)$ denote the size of minimum feedback vertex set of $G$.

We believe we proved $\chi(G) \ge (|G| - MFVS(\overline{G}))/2$
and this bound is sharp.

> Is this known or trivial result?

This is standard notation and to address comments
$|G|$ is the number of vertices of $G$, $\overline{G}$
is the complement of $G$ and feedback vertex set $S$ is subset of $V(G)$
such that deleting $S$ from $G$ leaves acyclic graph.

Comment: Is $\overline G$ the complement of $G$? Is $|G|$ the number of vertices? And what is a feedback vertex set of $G$?

Comment: @bof This is standard notation, yet I edited with the definitions.

Comment: It might be easier to think of $|G|-MFVS(\bar G)$ as the size of the largest induced subforest of $\bar G$.

Comment: Here is an easy proof: consider any proper colouring of $G$, with colour classes $n_1,\dots,n_{\chi(G)}$.  Then the complement of the complete multipartite graph is a collection of cliques, from each of which we can choose at most two vertices to have an induced subforest. Since this collection of cliques is a subgraph of $\bar G$, the largest induced subforest of the latter can only be smaller.

Comment: @MartinRubey Thanks :) My proof is different. Is this known? And can your solution compute the RHS in time n^(2*chi(G)) if chi(G) is given?

Comment: I have no idea because I rarely do graphs :-) I am sceptical that my proof yields a way to compute the right hand side in sensible time, because I need a colouring to start with!